# How do I get hold of the incoming byte over serial on Arduino?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I have the following Arduino code.

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        int b=Serial.read();
        Serial.println(b);
    }
}
```

If I open serial monitor and enter 00000001 I get the output

```
48

48

48

48

48

48

48

49
```

OK, so firstly why 48 (and last line 49) and secondly why so many lines?

I was expecting to get the simple output of '1'.

If I change the line `Serial.println(b);` to `Serial.println(00000001,DEC);`, I get exactly what I expect (that is, '1'). But if I change the line to `Serial.println(b,DEC);`, I get the same strange output as before.

Comment: You entered 8 characters and got 8 results.  The last character is different, being 1 instead of 0, the last result is different, being one higher....  Google 'ASCII table'.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand now. So when I replaced the line with Serial.println(00000001,DEC); it counts that as one byte while the serial monitor takes each digit as an integer?

Comment: How do I simulate a serial byte stream input in the serial monitor then?

Answer (score 5):

The 48 and 49 are decimal representations of '0' and '1'. It's printing 8 lines because you're calling Serial.println in a loop.

What exactly is your end goal? Serial.read() is returning the character, not the value: http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/read

Hope this helps!

--
Example:

```
if(Serial.available() > 0)
{ 
    int num = 0;
    for( int i=7; i>=0; i-- )
    {
        if( Serial.read() == '1' )
            num |= (1 << i);
    }
    Serial.println(num);
}
```

Comment: My goal is to enter a byte in binary and print this as an integer

Comment: Also why do the multiple lines not occur if I use the line Serial.println(00000001,DEC);?

Comment: would reading the serial byte of 00000001 into an integer not set the integer as 1?

Comment: If you use the same loop, it should still print multiple lines. Reading a serial byte of 00000001 into an integer would set it to be 1, but you're not sending 0000001, you're sending characters of '0' and '1'.

Comment: I added an example assuming you send the MSB first.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply resolve this by changing b = Serial.read() - '0'. This happens because the arduino is using decimal code, not char. Here is a conversion table: http://www.asciitable.com/.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to receive an ascii string '000001' and convert it to an integer. The following untested example will require a carriage return to indicate the end of the string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int x=0;
int char_rev;
char buf0[20];

while(buf0[x]!=0) {

    char_rev = Serial.ReadData(buf0[x],1);
    if (char_rev==1) {
        if (buf0[x]=='/r') {
            buf0[x]=0;
        }
        else {             
            x++;
        }
    }        
}
x=atoi(buf0[]);

Serial.Println(x);
```